# What test does summary() perform on a glm() model using a Gamma distribution in r?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I've fitted my data to a glm with a gamma distribution (as this is the most appropriate for the type of data) using the `glm()` function in R. I used the `summary()` function to test and get p values. I've received comments back from a publication submission which wants more details on the specific test that this does. I can't find any where which states what test this performed with this call. One place I saw said that this does a Wald test, however as far as I can tell a Wald test is a parametric test that assumes a normal distribution.

Can anyone provide some clarity on the specifics of what statistical test is providing the p values here?

EDIT

For clarity:

```
data <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("A","B"), each = 100),
                   Variable = c(runif(100, 1, 99), runif(100, 25, 124)))

model <- glm(Variable ~ Group, data = data, family = "Gamma")

summary(model)
```

returns

```
Call:
glm(formula = Variable ~ Group, family = "Gamma", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2135  -0.4441   0.0023   0.3474   0.6771  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0186047  0.0008493  21.905  < 2e-16 ***
GroupB      -0.0049861  0.0010526  -4.737 4.13e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.2084024)

    Null deviance: 64.352  on 199  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 59.505  on 198  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1937.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

This returns the expected result that these groups are significantly different, but what test was performed to calculate this.

In the manuscript I have written

"R (version 4.1.1) base functionality was used for all calculations and statistical analyses...data were fitted to generalised linear models using a gamma distribution with the glm() function, and groups compared by Wald tests against their respective, same age controls using the summary() function."

But a Wald test is a parametric test which assumes a normal distribution. Is R perhaps performing a Wald Log-Linear Chi-Square Test instead of a normal Wald test in these cases?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question to include the output from your `summary(model)`. Paste the output in, select it, and use the code `{}` tool to make it readable. There typically are three overall estimates of _p_ values for this type of model (likelihood-ratio, score, and Wald tests), plus estimates of differences of coefficients from values of 0 (Wald tests).

Comment: Thanks @EdM. I've added more detail, but I really just need to know what test gives the p values for the methods of a manuscript I've submitted. As far as I can tell a Wald test is a parametric test, assuming a normal distribution and therefore not appropriate for a glm.

Comment: With a reasonable sample size, the maximum likelihood estimate of $\hat{\beta}$ in a GLM is approximately normally distributed. This doesn't mean your predicted outcome needs to be. The Wald-type test is for this coefficient, not the full glm. See Chapter 4 of "Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models" by Agresti (2015) for more details.

Comment: Thank you awhug. How about for small sample sizes (n= 11 per group)? Could you perhaps suggest a reply to the reviewer who said "The Wald test was used to examine significant variables. I believe this is a parametric test which thus assumes a normal distribution of data. Was this tested or assumed?"

Comment: @lab_rat_kid The reviewer is likely not a statistician. The test is performed on the scale of the linear predictor and makes no assumptions about the *outcome*, let alone the *data*. You use a gamma GLM, which assumes the outcome is conditionally gamma distributed, given the effects of the explanatory variables. If *this* assumption is reasonable, then the assumption of the $t$ (or normal) distribution on the scale of the linear predictor likely is too. You can diagnose this with e.g., the package [`DHARMa`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But a Wald test is a parametric test which assumes a normal distribution. Is R perhaps performing a Wald Log-Linear Chi-Square Test instead of a normal Wald test in these cases?

The coefficients are maximum likelihood estimates, which are asymptotically normal.  The resulting test is <s>indeed a Wald test</s> *a t-test as noted by EdM*

There is a difference between the sampling distribution for the coefficients and the likelihood you're using.  Let me demonstrate.  Here is some code to generate data from a gamma distribution.  The shape and scale of the gamma distirbution depend on some variable `group`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
phi <- 10
group <- rep(0:1, 500)
mu <- exp( 1.5 + group)
y <- rgamma(1000, mu^2/phi, mu/phi)

tibble(group, y) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y, fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')
```

[image]

What I'm going to do is create these data 1000 times, run a regression, and look at the resulting distribution of the coefficients.  This is the sampling distribution of the beta. Here they are, stratified by the type of coefficient (intercept or for `group`).  You can see they are roughly symmetric and bell shaped.

There is much more theory to demonstrate their asymptotic normality, but perhaps this suffices to convince you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Demetri Pananos. Is this only the case for large n, or also smaller? I have 11 per group in my experiment, so not close to being large enough.

Comment: Is there any chance you could suggest a response to the reviewer who stated "The Wald test was used to examine significant variables. I believe this is a parametric test which thus assumes a normal distribution of data. Was this tested or assumed?"

Comment: With the dispersion estimated from the model with the gamma family, aren't these more appropriately called _t_-tests?

Comment: @EdM That is a good point and salient since OP has 11 observations per group

Comment: @lab_rat_kid. The reviewer's concern is about the likelihood and not about the sampling distirbution.  I would respond to the reviewer saying that the sampling distribution is approximately normal with sufficient data and hence Wald statistics are fine.  The validity of this assumption is up to you to defend since we don't have context or data to what you're studying.

Comment: I just checked `summary.glm`; if the dispersion is estimated from the model it performs a _t_-test.

Comment: My apologies for being so ignorant of the statistical methods, but is a t-test not also a parametric test?

Comment: @lab_rat_kid yes, but the model is parametric and -- with sufficient data (which is up to you to defend) -- the assumptions will be satisfied since the sampling dist of the coefs is normal and the estimated variance has approx chi square distribution.

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for your help. I will try to sound confident in defending the use of glm() and summary(). Out of curiosity, how would you perform a "true" non-parametric test in cases of insufficient data or where the data does not become asymptotically normal? Probably a very naive question, but I thought that using glm() would not put me in this situation.

Comment: @lab_rat_kid Look to techniques like the Mann-Whitney U test or similar

Answer (score 8):

Demetri Pananos makes the critical point about regression models (+1): the *coefficient estimates* are taken to have underlying multivariate normal distributions, at least in the asymptotic limit of large numbers of observations. That does not necessarily require a normal distribution of *data*, as the reviewer evidently thinks. In ordinary linear regression that doesn't necessarily even require a normal distribution of *residuals*, as the law of large numbers can lead to a normal distribution of *coefficient estimates* with a large enough data set.

The appropriate test to perform on the coefficient estimates depends, however, on whether the model is based on an assumed variance or if the model estimates the variance from the data. In ordinary linear regression you estimate both a mean value (as a function of covariates) and an error variance. In that situation you take the extra uncertainty from making dual estimates from the data into account by using a *t*-test.

In a generalized linear model (GLM) you could have either situation, depending on the family. The binomial and Poisson families, for example, have fixed associations between mean values and variances. If the choice of family is correct, there is no extra estimate of variance to make once the mean value has been estimated. As there is no independent estimate of variance, the correct test is a *z*-test for the probability that the normally-distributed coefficient estimate differs from 0. For a single coefficient that's equivalent to a single-coefficient Wald test.*

In the gamma family, however, the model fits both the coefficient estimates and a "dispersion" that defines *how much* the variance increases with the mean value. That's the same situation as in ordinary linear regression; the separate estimate of dispersion calls for a *t*-test with degrees of freedom based on the data size, instead of a *z*-test. The code for `summary.glm` makes that clear, as shown in the following snippet for the situation where `est.disp=TRUE` as for your gamma GLM:

```
>summary.glm

## much code omitted

pvalue <- 2 * pt(-abs(tvalue), df.r)
            coef.table <- cbind(coef.p, s.err, tvalue, pvalue)
            dimnames(coef.table) <- list(names(coef.p), c(dn, 
                "t value", "Pr(>|t|)"))

## much more code omitted
```

So the simplest way to address the reviewer's concern in your case is to apologize for your error and state that these are actually *t*-tests on the coefficient estimates. I suspect that if you had called them *t*-tests to start with there wouldn't have been a complaint, even though *t*-tests and *z*-tests and Wald tests are all based on underlying normal distributions of coefficient estimates (and not of "data").

---

*The general form of the [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test) is particularly important when there are multiple parameters to test together. For a single parameter, the Wald statistic is just the square of the *z* statistic and *p*-values are identical.

Comment: Good catch and adds important nuance +1.  Unrelated, I've encountered many who think that normality is a requirement for the t test as well, and so maybe the reviewer would have withheld the complaint but then again maybe not.

Comment: "the separate estimate of dispersion" a related question about the details of this is [Is there a Relationship Between Variance and Chi-Square?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589646/)