# fixest and glm iid standard errors for Poisson regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, standard-error

I am trying to manually compute iid standard errors for Poisson regression via the `fixest` package. Unfortunately, I fail to match `fixest` exactly - I am always slightly off.

Here's my implementation:

```r
library(fixest)

base = setNames(iris, c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3", "species"))
base$y_int = as.integer(base$y)

est = fepois(
  y_int ~ x1 + x2 + as.factor(species), 
  base,
  se = "iid", 
  ssc = ssc(adj = FALSE)
)

glm_est = glm(
  y_int ~ x1 + x2 + as.factor(species), 
  base, 
  family = "poisson"
)

X = fixest:::model.matrix.fixest(est, type = "rhs") 
Y = fixest:::model.matrix.fixest(est, type = "lhs")
weights = est$irls_weights
uhat = fixest:::resid.fixest(est)

XW = sqrt(weights)* X
XWX = crossprod(XW)
N <- nrow(X)
k <- ncol(X)

vcov1 = solve(XWX) * sum(
  weights * fixest:::resid.fixest(
    est, type = "response"
    )^2
  ) / (N-k)
diag(vcov1)

cbind(
  diag(vcov1), 
  diag(est$cov.scaled),
  diag(est$cov.iid), 
  diag(est$cov.unscaled), 
  diag(vcov(est)), 
  diag(vcov(glm_est))
)

# [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
# (Intercept)                  0.134124672 0.136024583 0.136024583 0.136024583 0.136024583 0.136024583
# x1                           0.012744117 0.012924641 0.012924641 0.012924641 0.012924641 0.012924641
# x2                           0.007314296 0.007417905 0.007417905 0.007417905 0.007417905 0.007417905
# as.factor(species)versicolor 0.085225170 0.086432407 0.086432407 0.086432407 0.086432407 0.086432407
# as.factor(species)virginica  0.148401944 0.150504097 0.150504097 0.150504097 0.150504097 0.150504097

diag(vcov1) /   diag(est$cov.scaled)
# (Intercept)                           x1                           x2 
# 0.9860326                    0.9860326                    0.9860326 
# as.factor(species)versicolor  as.factor(species)virginica 
# 0.9860326
```

The fact that all vcov elements are more or less off by a constant factor suggests to me that I am doing something wrong when computing the standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$

```r
diag(vcov1) /   diag(est$cov.scaled)
# (Intercept)                           x1                           x2 
# 0.9860326                    0.9860326                    0.9860326 
# as.factor(species)versicolor  as.factor(species)virginica 
# 0.9860326                    0.9860326
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the question are some mistakes in the computation of the estimate for the variance of the observations.

#### Poisson model

For a Poisson model we have $Var(y) = E(y)$ and the estimates of the variances are not based on the sum of squared residuals. Instead, it is based on the fitted Y values.

When using the following computations you get the right result

```
vcov1 = solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X)
```

That equation for vcov is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Parameter_errors_and_correlation and the matrix for the weights and the matrix for the covariance of the observations cancel each other.

#### Quasi Poisson model

The equation that you used is related to the estimation of the dispersion parameter like here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/590724/

If you compute it like

```
vcov1 = solve(XWX) * sum(1/est$fitted.values * fixest:::resid.fixest(est, type = "response")^2) / (N-k)
```

And compare it with glm that uses a quassipoisson model

```
glm_est = glm(
  y_int ~ x1 + x2 + as.factor(species), 
  base, 
  family = "quasipoisson"
)
```

then you get the same result

```
                                    [,1]
(Intercept)                  0.0048002929
x1                           0.0004561092
x2                           0.0002617771
as.factor(species)versicolor 0.0030501903
as.factor(species)virginica  0.0053112733
```

And the result is much smaller than the previous case because the Poisson model greatly overestimates the variance of the observations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the following small sample adjustment:

```
sum(weights * fixest:::resid.fixest(est, type = "response")^2) / (N-k)
```

The default VCOV has no adjustment:

```
diag(solve(XWX)) /   diag(est$cov.scaled)
#>                  (Intercept)                           x1                           x2 
#>                            1                            1                            1
#> as.factor(species)versicolor  as.factor(species)virginica
#>                            1                            1
```